# MVC / LINQ / Consolidate Iqueryable object

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, model-view-controller, iqueryable

I am beginner developer.

I have ASP .Net application base on ASP.NET and Entity Framework.

I built a controller  that generates three iqueryable objects from database.

Iqueryable 1

| Company | Model | Stock A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dell | Lat 5420 | 25 |
| Dell | Lat 5490 | 15 |
| Dell | Lat 7589 | 5 |
| HP | Eli 840 G6 | 15 |

Iqueryable 2

| Company | Model | Stock B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dell | Lat 5420 | 2 |

Iqueryable 3

| Company | Model | Stock C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dell | Lat 7589 | 5 |
| HP | Eli 840 G6 | 50 |

I would like to consolidate this 3 objects to one. Target is to pass this object to view  and print below result

| Company | Model | Stock A | Stock B | Stock C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dell | Lat 5420 | 25 | 2 | 0 |
| Dell | Lat 5490 | 15 | 0 | 0 |
| Dell | Lat 7589 | 5 | 0 | 5 |
| HP | Eli 840 G6 | 15 | 0 | 50 |

Thanks a lot for your help

Regards
François-Xavier DERVELOY
Paris

Comment: Along with the problem you should **include the code you have up until this point** (*make some effort to answer your problem/question as [so] is not a code writing service*). After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: Sounds like you are wanting to join the data sources and produce output based on those joins. This can be done using Linq or Lamdas and there is a lot of documentation on how to do this. Do a little research on this subject and then come back with *exactly* what is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood your data structure, but I hope the code below helps you.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var data = new List<StockRecord>();
    data.Add(new StockRecord() { Company = "Dell", Model = "Lat 5420", Stock = "Stock A", Count = 25 });
    data.Add(new StockRecord() { Company = "Dell", Model = "Lat 5490", Stock = "Stock A", Count = 15 });
    data.Add(new StockRecord() { Company = "Dell", Model = "Lat 7589", Stock = "Stock A", Count = 5 });
    data.Add(new StockRecord() { Company = "HP", Model = "Eli 840 G6", Stock = "Stock A", Count = 15 });
    data.Add(new StockRecord() { Company = "Dell", Model = "Lat 5420", Stock = "Stock B", Count = 2 });
    data.Add(new StockRecord() { Company = "Dell", Model = "Lat 7589", Stock = "Stock C", Count = 5 });
    data.Add(new StockRecord() { Company = "HP", Model = "Eli 840 G6", Stock = "Stock C", Count = 50 });
    var q = data
        .GroupBy(x => new{x.Company,x.Model})
        .Select(z => new {
            z.Key.Company,
            z.Key.Model,
            StockA = z.Where(y => y.Stock == "Stock A").Sum(y => y.Count),
            StockB = z.Where(y => y.Stock == "Stock B").Sum(y => y.Count),
            StockC = z.Where(y => y.Stock == "Stock C").Sum(y => y.Count),
        } );
    }
}
class StockRecord
{
    public string Company {get;set;}
    public string Model {get;set;}
    public string Stock { get; set; }
    public int Count  {get;set;}
}~~~
```